# Add Pause/Resume Button on Cycle

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle, resume

Hello I got this problem with the Pause/Resume button on Jquery cycle.

The pauseOnPagerHover works but not if I put an pausebutton in.

Like this one:

> ```
> $("#pauseButton").click(function() {
> $("#slideshow").cycle("pause");
> });
>
> $("#resumeButton").click(function() {
> $("#slideshow").cycle("resume");
> });
> ```

index.html:

> ```
> <a id="pauseButton" href="#">Pause</a>
> <a id="resumeButton" href="#">Resume</a>
> ```

*This is my slideshow.js script:*

> ```
>  $slideshow = {  
>         context: false,  
>         tabs: false,  
>         timeout: 4000,      // time before next slide appears (in ms)  
>         slideSpeed: 2000,   // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms)  
>         tabSpeed: 300,      // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms) when clicking through tabs  
>         fx: 'fade',   // the slide effect to use  
>         init: function() {  
>             // set the context to help speed up selectors/improve performance  
>             this.context = $('#slideshow');  
>             // set tabs to current hard coded navigation items  
>             this.tabs = $('ul.slides-nav li', this.context);  
>             // remove hard coded navigation items from DOM  
>             // because they aren't hooked up to jQuery cycle  
>             this.tabs.remove();  
>             // prepare slideshow and jQuery cycle tabs  
>             this.prepareSlideshow();  
>         },  
>         prepareSlideshow: function() {  
>             // initialise the jquery cycle plugin -  
>             // for information on the options set below go to:  
>             // http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html  
>             $("div.slides > ul", $slideshow.context).cycle({  
>                 fx: $slideshow.fx,  
>                 timeout: $slideshow.timeout,  
>                 speed: $slideshow.slideSpeed,  
>                 fastOnEvent: $slideshow.tabSpeed,  
>                 pager: $("ul.slides-nav", $slideshow.context),  
>                 pagerAnchorBuilder: $slideshow.prepareTabs,  
>                 before: $slideshow.activateTab,  
>                 pauseOnPagerHover: true,  
>                 pause: true
>
>             });  
>         },  
>         prepareTabs: function(i, slide) {  
>             // return markup from hardcoded tabs for use as jQuery cycle tabs  
>             // (attaches necessary jQuery cycle events to tabs)  
>             return $slideshow.tabs.eq(i);  
>         },  
>         activateTab: function(currentSlide, nextSlide) {  
>             // get the active tab  
>             var activeTab = $('a[href="#' + nextSlide.id + '"]', $slideshow.context); 
>             // if there is an active tab 
>             if(activeTab.length) { 
>                 // remove active styling from all other tabs 
>                 $slideshow.tabs.removeClass('on'); 
>                 // add active styling to active button 
>                 activeTab.parent().addClass('on');  
>             }  
>         }  
>     };  
>     $(function() {  
>         // initialise the slideshow when the DOM is ready  
>         $slideshow.init();  
>     });
> ```

What to add to make it work?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, i make one now. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xWbUn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#pauseButton").click(function() {
    $("#slideshow div.slides > ul").cycle("pause");
});

$("#resumeButton").click(function() {
    $("#slideshow div.slides > ul").cycle("resume");
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xWbUn/10/)

Comment: Thanks! :D Works like an charm!'